# iOS Location Services still used by an app even after killing in taskbar

Tags: core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an app that uses startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

The purple arrow in the upper-right appear when this is turned on.

I am doing some testing and occasionally I get to call stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

When this happens, even after I kill the app in Xcode, the purple arrow is still displayed.  I go into Settings.app -> Location Services and see the purple arrow is lit up beside my app, too, meaning it's still using it.
This does it even when running without Xcode connected to the device, and after I kill the app from the multitasking bar.

How can this be?

Shouldn't killing an app cause significant location change monitoring to stop?

This is definitely happening in 5.1... haven't tested with 5.0.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem as well, but I wasn't monitoring for significant location changes. It stemmed from using CLLocationManager AND having the Map View set to show the users location under the attributes in Xcode. Telling `[locationManager stopUpdating]` made my location manager stop sending messages, but messages from the Map View kept on a'comin. It wasn't until I told the Map View `[mapView setShowUsersLocation:NO]`that it quit. Not sure from your initial post if you are even using MapKit, but I thought I'd throw this out there just in case.

Comment: Good observation.  I am not using MapKit (at least, not when testing this), but this is something that could definitely cause that problem.

Comment: It solved my problem,thanks. I should read documentation more carefully.

Comment: This behavior seems like a bug. Any thoughts? I didn't notice any significant battery drain, but the location services icon in the status bar would never go away.

Answer (score 3):

You're certain you call `stopMonitoringSignificationLocationChanges` prior to background / termination?

Take a peek at the docs for [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) - this is probably the part important to you:

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives.

There are some pretty specific details in there about how to handle the data when you're terminated (inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`).

Comment: Since my original question, I've rewritten it to no longer use the location services background processing flag. When using
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(){}];
the app gets up to 10 minutes to do something. That's as long as I need to know about location updates.
However, the app still sometimes doesn't stop, even though my expirationHandler has the following two lines:
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

Any other ideas?